# sed/awk | single digits to two digits (zero) after a second slash

Tags: linux, awk, sed

maybe someone can help me briefly...
for example in file.txt...

```
nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/5
sed 's/\<[0-9]\>/0&/' file.txt ...
nw-3001-e0z-4581a/02/5
```

but I want the filled zero only after the second slash, the first number should remain a single digit

thanks in advance! greetz

Comment: Maybe `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$NF="0"$NF}1' file.txt` will do?

Comment: great, but not complete ;)... the example looks great: nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/05, but two digits were to three digits: nw-3004-e0-8D14a/1/020

Comment: Please, add a proper sample which describes the data thoroughly with the expected output, edit them to the original question, do not post them as comments or images. Thanks. Also, your sample adds zero after the first slash, not the second.

Comment: thanks James, a second sample further down, I will take care not to write it in the comments in the future, sorry

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples. Simply setting field separator and output field separator as `/` for `awk` program and then simply adding 0 before 3rd column(if there is only single digit present in it) and print the line.

```
echo "nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/5" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$3=sprintf("%02d",$3)} 1'
```

Comment: looks great, but not for already second-digits... echo "nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/12" | awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} {$3="0"$3} 1'   --> nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/012

Comment: sorry, my system does not know the function "sprint". the solution from Wiktor works ;) thanks!

Comment: @3rd1, Sorry that was typo, it should be sprintf, please do check it once and let me know how it goes cheers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use

```sh
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"} $NF ~ /^[0-9]$/ {$NF="0"$NF}1' file.txt
```

*Details*:

- `BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}` - sets input/output field separator to `/`
- `$NF ~ /^[0-9]$/` - if last field is a single digit
- `{$NF="0"$NF}` - prepend last field with `0`
- `1` - print tjhe result.

Comment: great :) thanks, it works! have a good day.

Comment: @3rd1 Just in case you want to avoid adding `0` to a `0`, you may use `/^[1-9]$/` instead of `/^[0-9]$/`

Answer (score 1):

Using sed:

```
sed -rn 's@(^.*/)(.*/)([[:digit:]]{1}$)@\1\20\3@p' <<< "nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/5"
```

Split the string into 3 sections using regular expressions (-r). Ensure that the last section has one digit only with [[:digit:]]{1} and substitute the line for the first and second sections, followed by "0" and the third section, printing the result.

Answer (score 1):

```
$ sed 's:/:&0:2' file
nw-3001-e0z-4581a/2/05
```

If that's not all you need then edit your question to show more truly representative sample input/output including cases that doesn't work for.